# Array of Substring in Java

Tags: java, string

I have scenario where, I have a string of numbers

```
String Lastnum = "123456789500020"
```

Expected results `firstnum = 1234567895` `secnum  = 00020 00030 00040`
I need to split this into two strings:

1. first for collecting 10 digit number and
2. second sec number.

The problem here is the second number is always dynamic not sure if it comes with two digits or five digits and the second number should be array of strings appreciate if you could let me know how to handle the code?

```
for (int i=0; i<Lastnum.length();i++)
{
    String ponum = Lastnum.substring(0,10);
    String[] item = Lastnum.substring(11, (Lastnum -ponum));
}
```

Comment: In your sample results, where do the 00030 00040 come from?  Those digits don't appear to be in your input.

Comment: sorry for the confusion caused , here is the input 380000012300010           read next 380000012300020 read next I have a while loop defined for reading this , so now I have only one po 3800000123 and two line items 00020 and 00030 so I need to send both po and array of line items for whole bunch of different PO's. hope you understand ...thank you so much for helping in this regard

Answer (score 2):

If the second part of the `String` looks like `secnum`, i.e. separated by space, you could do like this:

```
String ponum = lastnum.substring(0,10);
String[] item = lastnum.substring(10).split(" ");
```

I'm not sure why you added the `for` loop, it just repeats the same sequence of calculations `lastnum.length()` times.

Also, note that I changed the variable `lastnum` to start with a lowercase letter, to conform with Java's naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

the part regarding the sec number is not completely clear. What do you mean by dynamic?

Anyway,
what about:

```
String ponum = Lastnum.substring(0,10);
String sec = Lastnum.substring(10);
```

To start with?
I don't understand why you need an array of strings for sec. What should be the string in the first item? What in the second?

Answer (score 1):

```
String Lastnum = "123456789500020"
String firstNumber = Lastnum.substring(0,10);
String secondNumber = Lastnum.substring(10, Lastnum.length());
```

The above code will grab the first 10 (0...9) characters in the string, starting at index 0, and assign it to "firstNumber". It will then grab the rest of the characters, indexes (10... length of Lastnum -1).

If you're given an input like: String Lastnum = "123456789500020 00030 00040"
and want to return the first 10 digits [1234567895], plus an array of the remaining digits (denoted by a space)

```
String Lastnum = "123456789500020 00030 00040";
String ponum = Lastnum.substring(0,10);
String[] remainingNumbers= Lastnum.substring(10, Lastnum.length()).split(" ");
```

this essentially does the same thing as the first result but furthur splits the end of the string by the spaces

the results would be

```
ponum="1234567895"
remainingNumbers={"00020", "00030", "00040"}
```

In either case, there's no reason to loop through the string...

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, but I always I'll be getting the complete string with 15 digits as that number is po+item number which of collection POitems. like 123456789500020,            123456789500030  etc... i need to separate 10 digit and items array, as one po has many line items. please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to print the `secnum` infinitely with a space added between each member of it. You could try the following:

```
for(int i=0;;i++)
{
    ponum = lastnum.substring(0,10);
    item[i] = lastnum.substring(10)+" ";
}
```

Comment: That is never a good idea. infinite loop without a break? This will crash the program!